# How to prevent any game from running on a PC

Tags: gaming, restrictions

I am looking for an unbreachable way to disable the games running on my PC. Even games which require quite a low amount of graphics say 256MB should not work. It is to put restriction on gaming on my PC. I have a graphics card of 1GB and  2GB RAM and a processor of 2.7GHz with Windows 7.

Can we prevent a process from running if it takes a certain amount of graphics memory greater than a value set by user? I mean can we put restriction on games on the basis of the amount of graphics memory they use. Also the method should be applicable to all games (ignoring the chess and other small games like that. Even if it gets blocked, then also no problem.

**This is to prevent myself from playing games. But I need other software (non game) to run properly.**

Comment: Wouldn't something like Photoshop be restricted then?

Comment: Why not block software installation on non-Administrator accounts?

Comment: But that would mean no software can be installed without permission right??But i am looking for something specific like some way which would block games only.

Comment: @Bort thats a prob.Yup but since i hate photo editing that won't be a problem.I just need videos to run.Does videos require more graphics than what is required by photoshop?

Comment: Search for parental control software and their options

Comment: but restrictions must be put on each game (manually) right?What if i reinstall the game will it still work?I mean after setting parental control.

Comment: How is the system supposed to know what programs are games and what are not?

Comment: @DavidRicherby anything which uses high graphics memory...........well that would mean adobe photoshop will not work but that won't be a problem for me.....

Answer (score 2):

You can not have an "unbreachable" way to do this - once you have a physical access to a PC, its more-or-less game-over.   The best you can do is frustrate access to certain games - be it based on graphics requirements, access to (for example) Steam servers or limiting what can be installed by non-admin users on the system - and requiring people to log in other then as admin.

Comment: So can we put password on any application which requires high graphics(What i mean is a single password for any such application (the password should not be such that it has to be set for each application.It must be common and automatically set up by computer when it detects any high graphics application when it begins to run)).Or is there a way to reduce the amount of graphics memory provided to certain minimum value so that just simple things only runs(like video).